# SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have created a database using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio. I am having a problem with creating data in the tables.

I am using INSERT statements from inside the query window to input data into the tables.
When I do a SELECT after the INSERT I am able to see my data.

But when I right click on the particular table and select "Open Table" in the Object Explorer I am not able to see my data. The table is empty.

Why is this inconsistency between the Query Window and Object Explorer ?

Am I missing any settings here ?